# Reducible polynomial compositions

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n\geq 2$ with integer coefficients. Then there always exists a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $f\circ g(x)$ is reducible. Namely, let $g(x)=f(x)+x$; then $f\circ g(x)$ is divisible by $f(x)$. The degree of $f(f(x)+x)$ is $n^2$ which is quadratic in $n$, the degree of its factor $f(x)$.

**Problem:** *Does there always exist a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $f\circ g(x)=p(x)q(x)$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients that have degrees comparable to that of $f\circ g(x)$ (for example larger than a third of the degree of $f\circ g(x)$)?*

Comment: Reducible over what field? For example, if we are talking about reduciblity over polynomials in $\Bbb{C}$, then you can always factor $f\circ g$ into two polynomials whose degrees differ by at most $1$.  If, however, you are talking about reduciblity over polynomials with integer coefficients, then in general there is no such factoring.,

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Do you have an explicit example of an $f(x)$ for which such $g(x)$ does not exist?